# using adonis to compare to distance matrices

Tags: r, matrix, vegan

I have 2 two dissimilarity matrices. One with observed data comparing among 111 sites and another generated using a null model.

I would like to use the `adnois` function in `vegan` to test whether the observed dissimilarities differ  significantly from those expected by the null model. However the adonis function will only take one dissimilarity matrix on the left side of the formula.

Does anyone have any idea how to model this test?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you try Mantel or Partial Mantel Tests?

Comment: Ok, ive not looked into those. Will they tell me the same thing as a PERMANOVA would - i.e. whether observed vs null dissimilarities are significantly different from one another?

Comment: In a sense yes. Try `library(vegan)`; `?vegan::mantel`

Comment: So the mantel test tells me whether the dissimilarities for the two matrices are correlated but not whether their relative magnitudes differ significantly.

Comment: In vegan, you can use oecosimu() to build your own tests. See examples in ?raupcrick for handling dissimilarities. Using oecosimu() requires that you can build up a null model that is run on data, and you can build up a function for test statistic. It is recomended to use vegan 2.1-versions at R-Forge or github: they have better support for plugging in your own null model.

Comment: @JariOksanen. Welcome! vegan 2.1 will no longer be available at cran?

Comment: Thanks. Below is what I have tried. The goal is to test whether patterns of beta-diversity across my sites differ significantly from stochastic community assembly. I was using the algorithm from Chase et al which holds alpha and gamma diversity constant and then randomly shuffles the binary community matrix assigning the probability of species occupancies based on their observed occupancy.

Comment: meandis <- function(x) mean(raupcrick(x, nsimul = 999, chase=FALSE))

Comment: test <- oecosimu(com, meandis, nsimul = 999, "r1")

Comment: @PauloCardoso No, it will be available from CRAN. The r-forge and github versions are where development takes place prior to releasing new versions to CRAN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this problem was:

```
meanjac <- function(x) mean(vegdist(x, method='jaccard', diag=TRUE))
test <- oecosimu(x, nestfun=meanjac, method="r1", nsimul = 10^3, statistic='adonis')
```

which passes a function to get the mean of jaccard dissimilarity matrix to oecosimu, which then uses the 'r1' method to generate null community matrices by randomly shuffling the binary community matrix but assigning the probability of species occupancies based on their observed occupancy and comparing this to the observed dissimilarity matrix.

Thanks Jari for pointing me in the right direction...

Comment: This seems to be very nice but I'm not getting this completely... it means that the model will build 10^3 times the vegdist and test it the same number of times against the null community matrix with adonis?

Comment: oecosimu will build 10^3 "stochastic" community matrices using the "r1" algorithm and then use meanjac to get the mean jaccard dissimilarity from each of these and compare it to the mean of the observed community matrix. I think the statistic = 'adonis' is redundant actually.